# MongoDB Create Collection like MySQL CREATE TABLE

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework2

I am using `MongoDB` as a replacement for `MySQL` in `Zend Framework 2`, I was wondering, is there any `CREATE TABLE` statement like thing in MongoDB to create collections programmatically, most preferably within `ZendFramework 2`? Or maybe what is the approach one needs to take while creating DBs and collections when working with `MongoDB`?

Answer (score 1):

Collections are created automatically in MongoDB as soon as you try to save a document to them.

If you really, really want to have an empty collection, try inserting any document to it to create it and then delete the document. But generally it's best to just let MongoDB do its thing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yup this I  can see, it getting creating automatically but having so shortcoming

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB, a collection is created implicitly when you first insert a document into it. Nevertheless, you can create a collection explicitly with MongoDB by using the command `db.createCollection()`. This command will also allow you to pass options specifying the nature of the collection, such as whether it is a capped collection, what sort of validation it should have, indexing options, etc. The syntax for MongoDB 3.2 is as follows:

```
db.createCollection(<name>, { capped: <boolean>,
                              autoIndexId: <boolean>,
                              size: <number>,
                              max: <number>,
                              storageEngine: <document>,
                              validator: <document>,
                              validationLevel: <string>,
                              validationAction: <string>,
                              indexOptionDefaults: <document> });
```

For more information, you can visit [this page](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) in the documentation.

Regarding database creation, as of MongoDB 3.2 there is no method to explicitly create a database. So in order to create a database, you need to insert a document to a collection inside it, or create a collection directly using `db.createCollection()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info mate

Comment: Not a problem! I added a note about creating a database as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: I was looking for something using doctrine 2

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it looks like you can create a collection explicitly using `createDocumentCollection()`. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/capped-collections.html